# Which jvmTarget use for kotlin project?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, jvm

I use kotlin to writing backend service with gradle and comple it for 1.8 jvm. Is it any reason to switch jvmTarget from 8 to 12 version?

Answer (score 0):

This is highly based on **your** environment.

If you know your targeted/final environment will indeed be running Java 11+, then you can target Java 11+.

But if your environment is running Java 8, then you should target Java 8. And if you have other fellow developers that are on/stuck on Java 8, then you should probably target Java 8 as well.

Comment: That is entirely dependent on your application. You'll need to review the release notes for each release to determine that. Unless you have been collecting metrics or monitoring your application, you probably won't see a noticeable difference. But again, it all depends.